# Is requestAnimationFrame safe to use in React hook cleanup

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to resize a canvas when a sibling component mounts and unmounts. My stripped down JSX structure is this

```
<FlexContainer>
  <MyCanvasWrapper> // flex-grow is 1
    <canvas width="1000" />
  </MyCanvasWrapper>

  <MyComponent /> // static 300px width
</FlexContainer>
```

When `MyComponent` mounts, I need to call a resize function that will read the layout width of `MyCanvasWrapper` and set the canvas attribute to the same.

I'm using this hook in `MyComponent`

```js
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log('mount');
    resize();

    return () => {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        console.log('unmount');
        resize();
      });
    };
  }, []);
```

Visually this works like I want it to, but my gut is telling me that `requestAnimationFrame` in this context is code smell. If I just call `resize` like in the mount phase (the mount resize always works regardless of cleanup), the width doesn't change. I confirmed that my css and `resize` function are fine by attaching it to a button that I can click after the width fails to change. This leaves me with a nebulous call stack problem where the `useLayoutEffect` cleanup is being called too soon? I'm pretty clueless at this point.